# Cypress failed email notification

Tags: email, cypress

I am using cypress.io as automation tool I need to send email notification when my cypress test failed.
Is there any way to do it?

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Stack Overflow. This question is very broad; "how do I do this" questions are not likely to be answered. Please provide some details about your setup. If you haven't yet, attack the problem! When you get stuck, let us know what you have tried and what errors you're getting.

Comment: @JoshuaWade I tried the following thing given in this link https://github.com/bahmutov/cypress-failed-email#readme   but I didn't get where to put that in js file.const {formEmail} = require('cypress-failed-email')
const filename = process.argv[2]
//> failed-test.json for example
const failed = require(filename)
const email = formEmail(failed)
//> email is object with text fields {subject, plainText}

Answer (score 2):

You can always link it to another tool via command line. Basically, you pipe the exit code (-1) to an if statement and then run a mail command

An example is in this SO: https://serverfault.com/questions/252448/bash-script-alert-on-error

```
cypress run
if [ $? -ne 0 ]
then
    mailx -s "FAIL" your@email.com
```

Comment: Do I need to use this code in package.json filer or in my testspec.js file.

Comment: I'd make a bash file and run it from your package.json scripts

Comment: I tried that and test runs but on console I get following error message   > cypress.io@3.1.0 cypress:run F:\
> test.sh

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! cypress.io@3.1.0 cypress:run: `test.sh`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the cypress.io@3.1.0 cypress:run script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

Answer (score 1):

Instead, you should use [Module API](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/module-api#cypress-run). You can run cypress from a javascript file and get the results of running cypress.

Check here. https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/7441#issuecomment-632535986

Below is an example javascript.

```
// e2e-run-tests.js
const cypress = require('cypress')

cypress.run({ headless: true, browser: 'chrome' })
  .then(result => {
    const testResults = JSON.stringify(result, null, 2);
    // Module API uses "if (result.failures)", that didn't worked for me. That's why I check with "totalFailed > 0"
    if (result.totalFailed > 0) {
      console.log('Failure(s) in tests! Will send an e-mail')
      sendEmail(testResults);
    }
    process.exit(0);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log('Cypress didn't worked due to some error')
    process.exit(0);
  });
```

Also, note that inside the `sendEmail` method you should call `process.exit(0);` after the email is sent.